# Access Object AND property of object using variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am aware you can access properties of objects in javascript using variables like this `Object['property']` but I want to access the **Object** using a variable too.

```
// The object and his function
var Foo = {};
    Foo.bar = function() { console.log("I am a useful function dood"); }

// The accessors
var obj = 'Foo';
var method = 'bar';
```

But when I try it in the way I think is right, I get the following. As all links in the world seem to be about accessing object *properties* with variables I don't seem to be able to sift one out that accesses objects like this too.

```
typeof obj           // "object"
typeof Foo[method]   // "function"
typeof [obj].foo     // undefined
typeof [obj][method] // undefined <-- This is what I'm trying to use
```

Am I able to access the object like this?

EDIT

According to answers, if the object is globally scoped I could use `window[obj][method]` but the above is contained in an immediately invoked function like this:

```
(function(){
    // The stuff from above...
})();
```

Will this work I will have to put this into an identifiable var that is globally scoped?

PS I will never ever use eval();

Comment: `window[obj][method]()`

Answer (score 1):

If your `Foo` object is at the global object then :

`window[obj][method]()` //I am a useful function dood`

Else , you will need to supply more info.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense but the object is not in the global scope, it is in an immediately invoked function, like this:

    ````(function () {
        // All the stuff from above
    })();````

Is there any way of accessing it this way or do I need to make a reference to a globally scoped container for the functionality?